# How to find position of the edge of an object?

Tags: unity

I have two planes and I want to put both planes one after another so that I can form a road. I set them from the editor and that was very easy but I wanted to do this from code. So in the code:

```
void Start() {
  secondRoad.position = firstRoad.position;
}
```

But this just set the **second plane** in the center of the **first plane**, kind of overlapping. But I want the second plane to be placed next to the first plane where it ends right the edge of the first plane. How will I do this?

Comment: A plane has four edges. Which one do you want to place the second object at?

Comment: I want at the right edge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your pivots are in the centers of the objects, to line up the planes edge to edge horizontally you'll need to shift to the right by...

- half the width of the first (to reach its right edge from its center)
- plus half the width of the second (to reach its center from its left edge)

In this case both objects are standard Unity planes (width = 10), so assuming you haven't scaled them, the two halves add up to one whole and we get:

```
float spacing = 10f;
secondRoad.position = firstRoad.position + Vector3.right * spacing;
```

To handle arbitrary shapes without a size known in advance, you can use the [bounds of their renderers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) to determine the appropriate spacing.

Comment: it worked thanks, I want to know how would I find the width of any game object.

Comment: See the link in the final paragraph.